# How to trigger a certain animation in certain object when it touches

Tags: animation, particles

In my scene i have my bushes and my particle system(rain drops).I want to tweak my bushes when the particle rain drop touches it.

Comment: Is your Bush rigged or is it a Soft Body?

Comment: its just a soft body i made the model and  used as a particle group no further steps

Comment: Give me an hour to test my theory out. I want to see if it is possible using Dynamic Paint to pull this off. Since it uses your current existing Perticle system

Comment: I actually can't help. Its not possible to apply Dyn Paint onto a Soft Body in any way.

Blender calculates the Dyn Paint After the Soft Body calculation. I dont think there is another way than Force Fields and/or Rigging the the Bush with bones.